# Copy current file selection using batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file

Generally I have the need to copy .exe files from a shared network location to a fixed directory on my local drive. In order to speed this process up slightly, I thought I'd explore adding a Context Menu option which would copy the selected file to this fixed local folder.

Having decided to do this via adding a few Keys to the Registry to enable the relevant Context Menu options against .exes and having this option point to a Batch file, I can't seem to make that final step to copy the currently selected file (or files) to the local folder.

I understand the batch command COPY syntax, however all the examples I look at are to copy one specific file to another location. I want to replace 'one specific file' with 'the current selection'; if anyone has any ideas on how this can be done via Batch Commands, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd /k copy "%1" "c:\users\"
```

put straight into registry. No batch file needed.

PS: As you can see each file is processed individually. You cannot get all selected files with batch in one hit.

In addition to the op suggestion, whose name disappears while I edit, sendto uses drag and drop. So you can put the batch in quicklaunch or on your desktop and drag and drop your files in one hit.

Comment: change /k to /c to have window close after copying.

Comment: Excellent; much easier than pointing to another file! P.S. Once it was working I did change the /k to a /c and then saw your comment about it underneath =p

Answer (score 2):

If you launch the action from the shell registry key associated with `.exe` files, the command will be executed for each of the selected files (see [D.Ddgg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25028657/2861476))

If you want/need to use a batch file to process the list of selected files, an alternative is to use the `Send To` menu. Create the batch file

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Test if there is something to copy
    if "%~1"=="" exit /b

    rem Congfigure the script
    set "targetFolder=c:\somewhere"

    rem Do the copy - Iterate over the argument list (the files)
    for %%a in (%*) do copy "%%~fa" "%targetFolder%"

    pause
```

and create a link to the batch file inside the `Send To` folder (type `shell:sendto` in the address bar of explorer)

The list of selected files will be passed as separated arguments to the batch file. You should remember that there is a limitation in the length of the command lines, so, if the list of files needs more than 8KB characters (aprox), some of them will not be processed.

Comment: This is certainly something I'll add to my repository. Thanks very much =)